# Android SDK Manager fetching failed

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I've a big problem on my SDK Manager I got this this message :

```
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
Done loading packages.
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml,     reason: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10107: create
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml,     reason: Socket Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10107: create
Done loading packages.
```

I know that there's a lot the questions like mine but I've tried all the solutions like adding a proxy server to the **SDK Manager** and to the **Eclipse** and to the **Java** from the control panel, in addition I've checked :

```
Force https://... sources to be fetched with http://...
```

But nothing worked for me, please help me guys by the I'm using :

- Windows 8.1 x64
- Android bundle with revision : 20140702

And thanks to every one!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact problem as yours and I just solved it by disabling the **Public** **Inbound Rule** on Windows Firewall for `Java(TM) Platform SE binary`.

[WFN1.9.2.9](https://wfn.codeplex.com/workitem/1655) then popped up its Notifier upon attempting to start Android SDK Manager, I allowed, and then everything proceeded as normal.

Answer (score 0):

While On The SDK Manager panel, click on the TOOLs Menu,
then "Proxy settings" and Type in the: Proxy Server and Proxy Port in Here.
Make Sure The Proxy Port Matches the One You Use in Your Browser.
Hope That Solves Your Problem. it worked for Me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try pinging `dl-ssl.google.com` (173.194.72.136)

This worked for me when I got "BAD MAC" issues and it wouldn't complete downloads.